# In bash, how to open .png file in a Mac app which only has “import” in the app menu

Tags: applications, command-line, graphics

I'm using 'engauge Digitizer' to digitize the charts (.png file). When to automate the process, I wish to write bash script or to use Python Subprocess library to control it. The first step is to import .png file to the app.

However, 'engauge Digitizer' doesn't work like other Mac apps, which can use bash "open".

```
$ open -a Preview '/path_to_file/picture.png' # This works.
$ open -a 'engauge Digitizer' '/path_to_file/picture.png' # This does not work.
```

Could you give some help?

Comment: Thank you @klanomath! I've located the CLI. Now, I can open the app with [link]./engauge\ Digitizer. However, I've tried all the flags offered in the help, including -dropregression, -filecmdscript, <files>. No one works. Also I tried move the .png file to ~/Lib*/Contai*/Digitizer/Data/ directly/. 'Engauge Digitizer' doen't recognize its own default path either. What can I try next? Thanks

Comment: I see. My goal is to import the .png file (some line chart) to engauge digitizer. 
Will add a ticket. Thanks@klanomath!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*engauge Digitizer* indeed provides a CLI at least using the pkg installer [available at github](https://github.com/markummitchell/engauge-digitizer/releases/download/v12.1/digit-exe-osx-12.1.pkg) to install the app.

In theory you can simply enter a command in Terminal to either open a *.dig file (the native engauge Digitizer file format) or import one of the supported image formats (jpg/bmp/png etc.):

```
/Applications/Engauge\ Digitizer.app/Contents/MacOS/Engauge\ Digitizer -help
/Applications/Engauge\ Digitizer.app/Contents/MacOS/Engauge\ Digitizer ~/Data/test.jpg
/Applications/Engauge\ Digitizer.app/Contents/MacOS/Engauge\ Digitizer ~/Data/test.dig
```

The app (I've tested v.12.1 in 10.15.2 Catalina) has some serious sandbox issue though and even after enabling full disk access/Development/... for any app or exec involved, I get a deny-read warning in the Console in my whole user folder and all relevant subfolders:

> Sandbox:     Engauge Digitize(1981) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/user/Data
>   Violation:     deny(1) file-read-data /Users/user/Data
>   Process:      Engauge Digitize [1981]
>   Path:           /Applications/Engauge Digitizer.app/Contents/MacOS/Engauge Digitizer
>   ...

---

It works if you move the files directly to the container folder ~/Library/Containers/Digitizer/Data/ and open or import the files from there.

Importing files invokes some additional modal windows. I doubt that you can handle this with a shell script.

---

My advice: [file an issue](https://github.com/markummitchell/engauge-digitizer/issues) at the developer's github page.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! FYI .png file works for my test case.

Comment: @BridgetHuang How do you handle the "import wizard" in your python/bash script (after importing a jpg/png/bmp)?

Comment: Currently I didn't see the "import wizard" if using the bash script, but I know what it looks like. Can it be removed by changing the app settings?

Comment: @BridgetHuang Maybe, probably - I already uninstalled Engauge Digitizer from my VM (the testing device). BTW I'd slightly rephrase the issue you opened yesterday at the developer's github page: the command line options to open and import files already exist (and thus can't be added) but they only work in the Digitizer container itself. Throwing an error trying to import a file from other directories indicate, that something is/went wrong with the sandbox settings/entitlements of the app.